# com.sun.tools.xjc.maven2 giving No XSD files found even though xsd exist (java 11)

Tags: java, maven-2, pom.xml, jaxb2-maven-plugin

I am upgrading from java 8 to java 11. I'm attempting to use jaxb2-maven plugin to convert XSD files into java classes. when i run "mvn clean install" i get the below compile error

```
[INFO] Ignored given or default sources [xsd/dummy.xsd], since it is not an existent file or directory.
[INFO] Ignored given or default sources [xsd/MessageProcessingAck.xsd], since it is not an existent file or directory.
[WARNING] No XSD files found. Please check your plugin configuration.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  4.216 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-11-10T19:13:17-08:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:jaxb2-maven-plugin:2.4:xjc (Acknowledgement notification XML/WSDL binding) on project dsched-integration-ackn: : MojoExecutionException: NoSchemasException -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

my pom.xml

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>Acknowledgement notification XML/WSDL binding</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>xjc</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources/</schemaDirectory>
                            <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/generated/</outputDirectory>
                            <packageName>com.dgp.ds.ackn.ws.send.acknowledgement</packageName>
                            <sources>
                                <source>xsd/MessageProcessingAck.xsd</source>                               
                            </sources>
                            <args>-wsdl -b ${basedir}/src/main/resources/xsd/</args>
                        </configuration>                        
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>                       
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

I have tried following the directions from these posts. I still got the same error

[Maven jaxb2:xjc failing to generate code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30200807/maven-jaxb2xjc-failing-to-generate-code)

the above post is mostly dealing with a lower version that is not compatible with most of my dependencies

https://artofcode.wordpress.com/2019/02/26/jaxb2-maven-plugin-2-4-and-java-11/

This post did not have any effect, both XSD were still not found

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue by using the below plugins

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.15.1</version>
....
</build>
```